# Connection between 3v3 and 5v I2C without have a reference voltage

Tags: i2c, level-shifting

I've two board that must communicate trough I2C BUS. One operates at 3v3 and the other one at 5V. I unfortunately can't use a reliable level shift IC becouse the physical connector on the board share just ground and doesn't provide 5V reference.  This doesn't allow me to use also other methods without the other board reference.

How I can modify my board I2C bus, that operates at 5v, to allow reliable communication with the other board?

I've read about Zener diode with I2C, but comments about this make appear this system not safe.

Comment: What about ‚creating‘ a new 5V reference supply on the other board and then use level shift IC?

Comment: Which board is the master and which one the slave? If the 5 V board is the slave, and has pullups, then you could just connect the 3.3 V signals to it, if the input pins are 5 V tolerant, or with additional zener diodes, but then check if you can use it for the 5 V board, because the zener diodes would reduce the voltage.

Comment: Get the 5 V with a separate cable.

Comment: What boards are they? Some devices are 5V tolerant even if they run at 3.3V. Some devices that run on 5V might have 3.3V compatible logic levels. It all depends what devices there are, so can you provide more info?

Comment: The level shifter doesn't need a 5v reference. Providing the 5V side has pullups already in place you can use the classic MOSFET shifter.

Comment: @KevinWhite Thanks, your tip guided me to the right resource that solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's a classic FET based level shifter [here](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10441.pdf)

[image]

Comment: In this cases, since bus is shared with more device that will have this termination, should work?
https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/w99mrtuqm699/screenshot/1024x768/
https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/x6n9a4dh8585/screenshot/1024x768/

Comment: I don't know, I have no time to analyse the ones you show at the moment. Simulate them and see if they work. Why would you want to depart from NXP's solution?

Comment: I'll apply NXP solution because it works well. But since this termination will be fixed inside my board and exposed I2C pins will have this protection, I'm worry about what will happen if I'll connect two of these boards on the same I2C bus (like in the second image) and if also an additional 5v boards will be connected to the same bus.